# CSS Element is obscuring Xpath element

Tags: c#, css, selenium, webdriverwait

A temporary CSS element is obscuring the xpath element I want to click on.

Using Selenium in Visual Studio I am writing a testcase where an element is to be clicked. But when I run this testcase I get an error message telling me:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException Element <a href="#/app/customer/handling/devices"> is not clickable at point (105,221) because another element <div class="showbox layout-align-center-center layout-row ng-star-inserted"> obscures it
```

The obscuring element seems to be a CSS element. But when I manually go to this page, inspect the code and search for this css element 
`<div class="showbox layout-align-center-center layout-row ng-star-inserted">` I get no results.

I am therefore assuming that this CSS element is temporary and can only be identified for a couple of seconds while the page is loadning. This assumption is confirmed by the fact that if I put a static wait method `Task.Delay(4000).Wait();`in this testcase I am able to complete this testcase.

But I'm not interested in a solution where I use a static wait method in my code. I want to be able to wait for the temporary css to disappear so I can click on my desired xpath element.

This is my code:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div class='showbox layout-align-center-center layout-row ng-star-inserted'")));
//Waiting for temporary CSS element to be visible
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("div class='showbox layout-align-center-center layout-row ng-star-inserted'")));
//Waiting for temporary CSS element to disappear

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div/div[2]/nav[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a"))).Click();
//Click on "Handle Tools" link
```

As you can read by the comments in my code I do three things here:

```
1. I wait for the temporary CSS to be loaded
2. I wait for it to disappear
3. I click on the xpath element.
```

When I do this I get an error telling me the CSS selector I'm trying to find is invalid.

If I skip the first step and just wait for the CSS to disappear/be "invisible" it will check this too fast and look before the CSS element have started loading.

So either I'm not writing the By.CssSelector format correctly. Or the CSS element is called something else than Visual Studio is calling it in the error message I quoted above.

So please tell me if I'm using an incorrect way to identify this CSS element here:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("div class='showbox layout-align-center-center layout-row ng-star-inserted'")));
```

OR

Is there another way to dynamically wait out temporary CSS elements?

OR

Can I somehow confirm that the name of obscuring CSS element is actually called "div class='showbox layout-align-center-center layout-row ng-star-inserted'"?

Comment: Just FYI - You can use the Javascript to click on the element, when this kind of issue happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was that my CSS selector was indeed invalid. Removing the "div class=" in the beginning and adding a "." solved the problem.

Before:

```
"div class='showbox layout-align-center-center layout-row ng-star-inserted'"
```

After:

```
".showbox.layout-align-center-center.layout-row.ng-star-inserted"
```

Thanks to Asyranok for providing me with the correct format for my CSS selector.
I did not need the rest of your code in this case, instead I just copied the correct CSS format from your code into my solution and it worked. :)

I usually only use xpath when trying to identify an element so I'm not that used to CSS and what format to use.

Also thanks to JeffC for confirming my suspicion that I need to wait for the obscuring element to first load and **then** wait again for it to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not 100% sure what you mean by a CSS element. But I am thinking it is just a misnomer you may have picked up. But CSS is cascading style sheets. It is markup that defines the appearance of a Document Object Model (DOM) element.

XPath is an approach to defining the location of an element for a driver to find it and interact with it. Css selectors are an alternative approach to finding elements in the xml or html of a DOM. So there is no such thing as a "Css element" or an "XPath element". They are just "elements".

As for fixing the issue you are seeing, you could try this:

```
    //This is called an extension method. It adds methods to an existing class. This should go in a static class that is accessible to your driver.
    private static void WaitUntil(this IWebDriver driver, Func<bool> Condition, float timeout)
    {

        float timer = timeout;
        while (!Condition.Invoke() && timer > 0f)
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            timer -= 0.5f;

        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    }

driver.WaitUntil(() => driver.FindElementsBy(By.CssSelector(".showbox.layout-align-center-center.layout-row.ng-star-inserted").length == 0);
```

Also of note, your CSS Selectors in your description are completely invalid. I suggest reading up on them in a [tutorial like this one](https://htmldog.com/references/css/selectors/).

Comment: I agree with everything up until your code. The main issue is that if the popup takes a fraction of a second to appear, your wait will pass and will continue and OP will still have the same problem. His approach was the correct one but his CSS selectors were not valid.

Comment: This code will work fine. If it takes time to appear, there are alternate ways to wait for it like an extra step. I am not saying his code is wrong to use Selenium waits. I am just showing him what I use. What I use allows any Boolean condition. Not just Selenium specific conditions, which is why use it.

Comment: There is a race condition on first entry into the `WaitUntil()` method... if the popup isn't visible, the condition will pass and it will fall through and then possibly run into the popup. You *HAVE* to wait for the popup to be visible, then invisible to remove this race condition.

Comment: Yes, you just said that. And said, one can simply add one extra line of code to handle that possibility. A line to wait for it TO exist, and then add the second line to wait for it to NOT exist anymore. And one can pass in a short wait time to handle it appearing. Wait 1 second for it to exist. Wait 5 seconds for it not to exist, for example. This isn't a hard thing to work around with my example above. And your entire claim about why this doesn't work is based on a presupposition anyway. Either way, this is easy to work around.

Comment: ... and yet you still haven't corrected your answer. You aren't waiting for it to appear and disappear, you are only waiting for it to be `count == 0` which could happen on first pass *before the element even exists.* If you understand this, why don't you fix your answer?

Comment: I am not changing my answer based on your "well suppose his obscuring element works this way" comment when there is no evidence that it does. Please feel free to answer him yourself if my answer does not satisfy you. Based on the evidence presented, it certainly seems like the element exists on DOM ready state, which this handles.

Comment: No, that's the way ALL elements like this work. There is a chance that your code will perform a check before the element appears. That's why it's called a race condition. You can leave it like it is and hope that it never fails and you won't understand why or you can do it the right way and never have to worry about it. I guess it is your choice.

Comment: "No, that's the way ALL elements like this work." What did I say about "all" elements? A race condition is when a thread of code requires information that a second thread would normally supply, but due to processor time, may not supply by the time the first thread reaches the operation in question.

Comment: I am not going to argue this. Like I said, I am not going to continue making updates based on "what if this works this way even though there is no evidence that it does". I gave them an answer that will work for them. They can modify and consume it any way that they need. I cannot handle every permutation or possibility around this. All I can do is answer it based on the information given to me. Thanks for pointing out your concerns. It is a useful thing  to note, so I thank you. But on the same token, I am not obliged to do what you expect me to either.

Comment: "ALL elements **like this**"... meaning web pages that contain elements that trigger popups. Your definition of race condition is too specific. [See the actual defintion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Race conditions can involve other things also like I described. If the page is slow, your code could check for the popup before it is launched. I feel like I keep repeating myself over and over... read my above comments.